# How can multi search in Elasticsearch for python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

```py
body = 
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "must":{
        'terms':{
           "reason":["A","B"] 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The 'reason' is  in _source.
I want  to find reason A or reason B  given  the index='test_index' by python.
But this code can't find.
The result is empty.

I use this "/_search?q=reason:A|Bsize=50&from=5000",the result is correct.
I want to get the same result in Python.
How can I do?

Comment: Can you add your mapping and sample data

Comment: @jaspreetchahal ,How can I add the mapping ?

Comment: Please update in question, did you try what @artem has written?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" :{
      "should" : [
        { "term" : { "reason" : "A" } },
        { "term" : { "reason" : "B" } }
      ]
    }
  }
 }
```

`must` is strict search and analogous to `AND` in sql query. `should` is analogous to `OR` in sql

Comment: The result is also empty.

I use this"/_search?q=reason:A|Bsize=50&from=5000",the result is correct.
Why?

Comment: You need to use `post` method with _search to search through the index. What method call are you using to search?

Answer (score 0):

It's not about Python when you use body as dict of your query.

> Terms Query:
>   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/query-dsl-terms-query.html
>
> ES Client for Python:
>   https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/

It should works:

```
body = {"query":{"bool":{"must":{'terms':{"reason":["A","B"]}}}}}
res = es.search(index="test-index", body=body)
```

Check:

```
res['hits']['hits']
```